# What is the best way to implement asynchronous "priority" chunking?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.7

The closest implementation I can find is that of aiostream's [chunks](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chunks). Which allows the generation of "chunks of size n from an asynchronous sequence. The chunks are lists, and the last chunk might contain less than n elements".

I have implemented something similar but the key difference is that it prioritises fulfilling one batch at a time as opposed to multiple batches at once.

```
import asyncio
import aiostream
from collections import deque


class IterableAsyncQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def put(self, value):
        await self.queue.put(value)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        return await self.queue.get()


class Batch:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.batch_size = n

    def __call__(self, iterable, *args):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.calls = deque()
        self.pending = set()
        self.pending_return = asyncio.Queue()
        self.initialised = False
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        iterable = iter(self.iterable)
        return iter(lambda: tuple(itertools.islice(iterable, self.batch_size)), ())

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        self.pending |= {asyncio.create_task(self.iterable.__anext__()) for _ in range(self.batch_size)}

        if self.initialised:
            future = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
            self.calls.append(future)
            await future
        else:
            self.initialised = True

        batch = []
        while len(batch) < self.batch_size:
            done, _ = await asyncio.wait(self.pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            done = list(done)[0]
            batch.append(await done)
            self.pending.discard(done)

        next_call = self.calls.popleft()
        next_call.set_result(None)
        return batch
        

async def consumer(n, a):
    start = time.time()
    async for x in a:
        print(n, x, time.time() - start)

async def producer(q):
    for x in range(50):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await q.put(x)

q = IterableAsyncQueue()
# a = Batch(5)(q)
a = aiostream.stream.chunks(q, 5)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(producer(q))
loop.create_task(consumer(1, a))
loop.create_task(consumer(2, a))

loop.run_forever()
```

The output using aiostream.stream.chunks:

```
1 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] 4.542179107666016
2 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] 5.04422402381897
1 [10, 12, 14, 16, 18] 9.575451850891113
2 [11, 13, 15, 17, 19] 10.077155828475952
```

The output using my implementation of priority batch:

```
1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 2.519313097000122
2 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 5.031418323516846
1 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 7.543889045715332
2 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 10.052537202835083
```

It seems to me that the priority batch is fundamentally more useful as it yields results sooner than [chunks](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chunks) allowing the calling code to await another batch. This means that if there are m consumers each awaiting a batch of size n then there are always between m×n and (m-1)×n results being waited upon. With the [chunks](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chunks) implementation the number of results being waited upon varies between m and m×n.

What I would like to know is why haven't I been able to find an implementation of this before and is this the best way of implementing this solution?

Comment: This looks like more of a codereview than a StackOverflow question. We can't objectively answer either of the questions in your last paragraph.

Comment: One worrying aspect of the code is that the queue is unbounded, so if the producer is faster than the consumer, it will buffer the elements indefinitely without providing any backpressure, which is a memory leak. Another issue is that `done = list(done)[0]` looks wrong - `wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` _can_ return more than one future in `done` if multiple futures complete in the same event loop iteration. (`Future.set_result` only _schedules_ execution of done callbacks, it doesn't call them immediately, so it's perfectly possible for multiple `set_result`s to happen "at once".)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise there was a code review stack exchange. I will look into providing backpressure because I am experiencing a memory leak in the code that this is written for. You're entirely right about asyncio.wait, I've definitely implemented that wrong.

Comment: Only one call executes at a time starting with the first as dictated by `if self.initialised`. The next call is allowed to continue executing when it's future is fulfilled. Perhaps [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Also, I find it confusing that `Batch` has all of `__iter__`, `__aiter__`, and `__call__`. Is it supposed to be iterated synchronously or asynchronously? That's not idiomatic Python API.